# periodic check to see whether Wifi in enables in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that will periodically check whether Wi-Fi is enabled in android and depending on on the result it will take an action. Can anyone give me some suggestions regarding this?

Thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 1):

I think you would better implement a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) listening to [WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) system intents.

This way you don't drain battery with unnecessary system wakeup for starting your periodic service, and you are guaranteed to track all wifi state changes.